# How to update UI dynamically in a compiled flutter App?

Tags: javascript, webview, dart, flutter

I want to update my mobile app dynamically which compiled from flutter, and now I've got three thoughts:

1. Write some dart function which can modify UI from parameters.
2. Fetch the new dart code directly into the app(not sure).
3. Use JSCore(webview) for some dynamic updating through javascript.

The modification could be a lot, the first thought might not good enough, which would make my app to big? I hope the second way can works, though it's said dart running in dart-vm, I'm not sure if it works.

For the JSCore(webview), It might be the final solution? but is there any other way to solve this question?

The app in my mind, is just like [expo](https://expo.io).